# Energy of restricted Lebesgue measure

Tags: integration, potential-theory

I'm a bit lost don't know why. We defined the potential $u_{\mu}$ of a Radon measure $\mu$ as the convolution of the meaure with the logarithm:

$u_{\mu}(x)=-\int \log|x-y| d\mu(y) $

and the energy $I(\mu)$ of the measure as the integral over the potential:

$I(\mu)=\int u_{\mu}(x)d\mu(x)$

I'd like to compute the energy of the Lebesgue measure restricted to a compact ball $\overline{B}_R$.

---

Comment: The definition you state works only for plane domains, i.e. on $\Bbb R^2$: the fundamental soluiton for the laplacian in $\Bbb R^n$, $n\ge 3$ changes its structure, so the energy of a mesure $\mu$ on higher dimensional domains changes accordingly.

Comment: Ok fine, then what happens in n=2 to start with

Comment: I think that you will find useful to have a look at the "[*Capacity*](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Capacity#References)" entry on the onlyne encyclopedia of mathematics. It seem complex but it will shed light on your problem.